# Parsing XML and populating custom ListView; where should everything be done?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-adapter, populate

I'm currently working on an Android app which parses some XML and puts it into a ListView. I had it working with a StringBuilder object being put into a TextView, but upon coding my adapter I can't get my ListView to be populated.

I was following this tutorial: [Using an ArrayAdapter with ListView](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView) and at the moment my code follows it pretty closely, yet I'm getting a blank output.

I'm thinking that perhaps since it's not mentioned in the tutorial, the adapter or something else should be coded somewhere other than MainActivity?

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"


    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/mainList" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**list_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:padding="6dip" >


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:id="@+id/titleView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:id="@+id/summaryView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/titleView"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:id="@+id/priceView"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
```

**Entry.java**

```
public class Entry
{
    public String title;
    public String summary;
    public String price;

    public Entry (String title, String summary, String price)
    {
        this.title = title;
        this.summary = summary;
        this.price = price;
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    TextView xmlTV;
    ListView listView;

    ArrayList<Entry> entries = new ArrayList<Entry>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mainList);

        ArrayList<Entry> arrayOfEntries = new ArrayList<Entry>();
        EntryAdapter adapter = new EntryAdapter(this, arrayOfEntries);
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mainList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        new PerformAsyncTask().execute();
        Log.d("PerformAsyncTask", "execute asynctask");

        adapter.addAll(entries);
        Log.d("PerformAsyncTask", "Add all entries to adapter");
    }


    private class PerformAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
    {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
        {

            String newTitle = null;
            String newSummary = null;
            String newPrice = null;

            try
            {
                URL input = new URL("https://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/toptvepisodes/limit=25/genre=4008/xml");

                XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
                factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
                XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();

                xpp.setInput(getInputStream(input), "UTF_8");

                int eventType = xpp.getEventType();

                while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT)
                {
                    if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG)
                    {
                        if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("title"))
                        {

                            newTitle = xpp.nextText();
                            Log.d("PerformAsyncTask", "Add title");
                        }

                        if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("summary"))
                        {
                            newSummary = xpp.nextText();
                            Log.d("PerformAsyncTask", "Add summary");
                        }

                        if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("price"))
                        {

                            newPrice =  xpp.nextText();
                            Log.d("PerformAsyncTask", "Add price");

                            Entry newEntry = new Entry(newTitle, newSummary, newPrice);
                            entries.add(newEntry);
                            Log.d("PerformAsyncTask", "Entry added");
                        }

                    }

                    eventType = xpp.next();
                    Log.d("PerformAsyncTask", "Skip to next item");
                }
            }

            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            }

            return null;
        }
    }

    public class EntryAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Entry>
    {
        public EntryAdapter (Context context, ArrayList<Entry> entries)
        {
            super(context, 0, entries);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            Entry entry = getItem(position);

            if (convertView == null)
            {
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_view, parent, false);
            }

            TextView tvTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.titleView);
            TextView tvSummary = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.summaryView);
            TextView tvPrice = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.priceView);

            tvTitle.setText(entry.title);
            tvSummary.setText(entry.summary);
            tvPrice.setText(entry.price);

            return convertView;
        }

    }

    public InputStream getInputStream(URL url)
    {
        try
        {
            return url.openConnection().getInputStream();
        }

        catch (IOException e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like you forgot to add the list to the ListView.

Comment: Add the end of `doInBackground()` you need to add the list to adapter. Something like this: `adapter.addAll(entries);`

Answer (score 0):

You forget to add the list to the Adapter. At the end of your AsyncTask doInBackground() at the list:

```
private class PerformAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    ...
  @Override
  protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
     ...
     adapter.addAll(entries);
  }
}
```

Or you can use `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` also.

Answer (score 0):

you may change the code like this

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    TextView xmlTV;
    ListView listView;

    ArrayList<Entry> entries = new ArrayList<Entry>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mainList);

        //ArrayList<Entry> arrayOfEntries = new ArrayList<Entry>();
        EntryAdapter adapter = new EntryAdapter(this, entries );
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mainList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        new PerformAsyncTask().execute();
        Log.d("PerformAsyncTask", "execute asynctask");

        //adapter.addAll(entries);
        Log.d("PerformAsyncTask", "Add all entries to adapter");
    }


    private class PerformAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
    {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }


        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
        {

            String newTitle = null;
            String newSummary = null;
            String newPrice = null;

            try
            {
                URL input = new URL("https://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/toptvepisodes/limit=25/genre=4008/xml");

                XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
                factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
                XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();

                xpp.setInput(getInputStream(input), "UTF_8");

                int eventType = xpp.getEventType();

                while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT)
                {
                    if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG)
                    {
                        if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("title"))
                        {

                            newTitle = xpp.nextText();
                            Log.d("PerformAsyncTask", "Add title");
                        }

                        if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("summary"))
                        {
                            newSummary = xpp.nextText();
                            Log.d("PerformAsyncTask", "Add summary");
                        }

                        if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("price"))
                        {

                            newPrice =  xpp.nextText();
                            Log.d("PerformAsyncTask", "Add price");

                            Entry newEntry = new Entry(newTitle, newSummary, newPrice);
                            entries.add(newEntry);
                            Log.d("PerformAsyncTask", "Entry added");
                        }

                    }

                    eventType = xpp.next();
                    Log.d("PerformAsyncTask", "Skip to next item");
                }
            }

            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            }

            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute()
        {
            super.onPostExecute();
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    }

    public class EntryAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Entry>
    {
        public EntryAdapter (Context context, ArrayList<Entry> entries)
        {
            super(context, 0, entries);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            Entry entry = getItem(position);

            if (convertView == null)
            {
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_view, parent, false);
            }

            TextView tvTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.titleView);
            TextView tvSummary = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.summaryView);
            TextView tvPrice = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.priceView);

            tvTitle.setText(entry.title);
            tvSummary.setText(entry.summary);
            tvPrice.setText(entry.price);

            return convertView;
        }

    }

    public InputStream getInputStream(URL url)
    {
        try
        {
            return url.openConnection().getInputStream();
        }

        catch (IOException e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```